# Killing all processes of current user

Tags: linux, kill, process

`user@host$ killall -9 -u user`

Will it definitely kill all processes owned by `user` (including forkbombs)?

1. No new processes is spawned to `user` from other users.
2. No `user`'s processes are in D-sleep and unkillable.
3. No processes are trying to detect and `ptrace` or terminate this started `killall` (but they can ptrace or do other things with each other)
4. There is `ulimit` that prevents too much processes (but `killall` is already started and allocated it's memory)

E.g. if `killall` will finish untampered and successfully is it 100% that no processes are left with this uid? If no, how to do it properly (with standard commands and no root access).

Will SysRq+I definitely kill all things (even replicating)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `killall` first [lists all processes](http://psmisc.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=psmisc/psmisc;a=blob;f=src/killall.c;h=8b590c27eabec58d2618081c5472f12676d41372;hb=HEAD#l346) that are to be killed, and then iterates through that list and kills them. If you have a forkbomb running, after `killall` will kill one of its processes, it is very likely that another process will immediately reclaim PID which has just freed, but `killall` thinks it already killed that process, so effectively nothing will happen.

You should use [ulimit](http://webtools.live2support.com/linux/ulimit.php) if a forkbomb is a problem for you. Limit number of processes to, for example, 128, and a forkbomb will silently die or stop expanding, depending on how it was written. Anyway, it will not present any danger to other users of that system.

Comment: `ulimit` is of course already in use for guest account. How to stop a forkbomb when it is running whithin `ulimit`  (from the same account)?

Comment: From the same account? How will you start a `killall`, if all pids are allocated to forkbomb? And if you can, first do `killall -STOP -u user`, thus preventing the bomb from propagation, and only then kill it with `killall -9 -u user`.

Comment: Of course, if you really want to and can do that from the same account, you must somehow tell `killall` not to stop your shell (and self, probably).

Comment: man killall: `killall process never kills itself (but may kill other killall processes).`

Comment: @Vi: ah, that was pretty stupid. but the shell problem still arises.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to deal with many forkbombs on a publicly accessible CTF server. I already had ulimits in place with pam_limits. For most forkbombs, you can do this:

```
killall -v -STOP -u mallory; killall -v -9 -u mallory
```

The STOP signal freezes the processes so killall has a chance to list them all and kill them.

But for typical python forkbombs, as soon as the ulimits are reached, the forking process will exit with an exception. This means that if your ulimit on nproc is 500, you will have a steady state of around 500 python processes, but each process will only be running for milliseconds at most. When I tried the above approach, by the time killall sent any given python process a signal, it had already exited.

The most important thing I learned came from `killall(1)`:

```
   -g, --process-group
          Kill the process group to which the process  belongs.  The  kill
          signal  is  only sent once per group, even if multiple processes
          belonging to the same process group were found.
```

Thus, this will probably do what you want:

```
killall -9 -v -g -u mallory
```

Alternatively, you could do a `killall -STOP` instead and inspect the now quiescent processes and kill them at your leisure. You can use the `CONT` signal to resume them, if desired.

Comment: Stopping the processes before killing is good idea (as it prevents reclaiming resources and spawning new processes). Only need to be careful not to free one's own shell (we are cleaning up a forkbomb without root access)